# PHP Header location not working / no HTTP Status: change

Tags: php, http, nginx, header, location

I'm facing a problem using Headers in PHP. `header('location: http:google.com');` is not working. This is my code:

```
if(!headers_sent()){
    header("location: http://google.com");
    exit;
}

HTML Data...
```

Script is exiting but `header()` is not working.

- I've already checked in my php.ini for `output_buffer` param and it's set to 4096.
- There are not extra lines above PHP opening tag
- and my script is encoding in UTF-8 w/o BOM.
- All errors are enabled but I'm getting no errors/warnings/notices. What is happening?
- Environment: PHP 7.0.27 and NGINX.

Later attempts and debugging steps concluded:

- `header("location: http://google.com";, true, 302);` made no difference
- `header("Refresh: ...")` did succeed.
- HTTP response debugging (after being asked a couple of times):

  ```
  StatusCode : 200 
  StatusDescription : OK 
  Content : <br />  <b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE in ...
  RawContent : HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
  Connection: keep-alive 
  Pragma: no-cache 
  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate 
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
  Date: Fri, 18 May 201... 
  Forms : {} 
  Headers : {[Transfer-Encoding, chunked], [Connection, keep-alive],
  ```

Unanswered still:

- `header("Status: 303 etc");` vs. `header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');` from the duplicate
- State of [`cgi.rfc2616_headers`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.cgi.rfc2616-headers)
- PHP SAPI
- Running the sample code outside the phar.

Comment: Are you sure that the second `header()` is executed?

Comment: Try putting Location instead of location. I think it's case sensitive.

Comment: `set_error_handler("var_dump");` and showcase the `wget -S` output for that test script.

Comment: @XerShade I already tried it, still not working.

Comment: @Mehdi I echoed a message within the if clause, and the message was displayed. That means that headers haven't been sent yet.

Comment: Go to the network tab in your browser and check the response headers

Comment: @Mehdi "This request has no response data available".

Comment: @mario Sorry, but could you explain the steps? I've put `set_error_handler("var_dump");` above `header()`. What should I do now?

Comment: @ProtectedVoid run "wget -S url-to-script" and it should get the output.

Comment: If no warning shows up, might indicate an NGINX and PHP-FCGI setup issue rather (nothing can be deduced from that code sample really). Hunt for either php or nginx logs. And run `wget -S http://localhost/yatestscript.php` on the console.

Comment: @XerShade My NGINX server is running locally in Windows. Is there `wget` equivalent I can try?

Comment: @ProtectedVoid If you are using powershell try this `$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient`
`$client.DownloadFile("url","file.txt")`

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150717/with-nginx-php-fpm-location-header-sometimes-ignored-by-browser-why -- Also: Powershell `Invoke-WebRequest`

Comment: @XerShade Powershell solution worked, I'm getting two PHP 'notice'.

Comment: Try adding this before the location call. `header("HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect");`

Comment: @XerShade That didn't make a difference.

Comment: You said you got two notices, what were they?

Comment: @XerShade Both are 'undefined index' for `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` and `HTTP_USER_AGENT`. I'm assuming I'm getting these 'notice' because the request was sent from Powershell? As I'm getting no notice when requesting from browser. I just disabled PHP notice messages from php.ini, but still not working.

Comment: Another little thing but try removing the space between the : and the h on the location line.

Comment: @XerShade No luck :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171277/discussion-between-xershade-and-protectedvoid).

Comment: @mario How is this a duplicate of what you said it is, he has said multiple times that there is no error, so how can you tag it as a duplicate of that error.

Comment: @mario none of the answers in the other question work for me

Comment: @XerShade I'll leave this as duplicate until access/error.log and the required HTTP raw debug output have been edited in. In it's current form the question is unanswerable. (Look at the answers this got so far. Elaborate debugging chat notwithstanding). Summon me when something worthwhile comes up.

Comment: @mario I have a semi-solution that works, could you please unlock the question.

Comment: @XerShade No probs. However, I would politely request someone edit the attempts and header debugging from the chat in here. Else an answer/workaround would be slightly misleading to future visitors. (Or: your answer might better fit as post on the second duplicate otherwise. Because that one contains all the necessary details to be useful/reproducible.)

Comment: Note: this is pretty much still a duplicate of [With nginx/php-fpm, location header sometimes ignored by browser. Why?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4150717)

Answer (score 1):

Right, this is not so much as a fix to the problem but a work around to get redirects working client side while you're on your development server. I wrote up a middle ware function to generate the redirect headers for you, simply add it to your code then call `Redirect("URL");`.

```
<?php

function Redirect($location, $delay=0) {
    // Check to see if the header are already sent.
    if(!headers_sent()) {
        // Check to see if we want Refresh because Location isn't working.
        if(defined('REDIRECT_ALTERNATIVE')) {
            // We want Refresh, let's go!
            header("Refresh: $delay; URL=\"$location\"");  
            exit;
        }

        // We want to do this server side, do it!
        header("Location: $location");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Now that you have this function all that you need to do is in a file, preferably a constants or config file, use the code `define('REDIRECT_ALTERNATIVE', true);` then that will enable client side redirecting, when you are done simply comment or remove that definition and it will switch back to server side.

Again this is not a solution as much as it is a work around, but after hours of testing with the OP this is what we managed to come up with.

Edit: For anyone who is wondering what the actual problem is, the OP's development server, for whatever reason, is always setting the http code to 200, even if we changed it manually, since I had no way to access his pc and debug his setup I came up with a workaround that avoids the need for his server to manage the redirects.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
     header("Refresh: $seconds; URL=\"$location\"");
```

Comment: I tested his original code, it works fine on my server so the issue is his server config.

Comment: So, what is the issue?

Comment: This header worked, it redirected to target location. But why "Location" header is not working?

Comment: @ProtectedVoid i do not know that, but if this works, you can check this answer as useful. Thanks.

Comment: Refresh works because it is client side, Location is server side where the issue is.